# NodeJS Polling per User Structure best practice

Tags: node.js, multithreading, service, polling, worker

My project is a full stack application where a web client subscribes to an unready object. When the subscription is triggered, the backend will run an observation loop to that unready object until it becomes ready. When that happens it sends a message to the frontend through socketIO (suggestions are welcome, I'm not quite sure if it's the best method). My question is how do I construct the observation loop.

My frontend basically subscribes to the backend, and gets a return 200 and will connect to the server per Websocket (socketIO) if it got subscribed correctly, or an error 4XX code if there was something that went wrong. On the backend, when the user subscribes, it should start for that user, a "thread" (I know Nodejs doesn't support threads, it's just for the mental image) that polls an information from an api every 10 or so seconds.

I do that, because the API that I poll from does not support WebHooks, so I need to observe the API response until it's at the state that I want it (this part I already got cleared).

What I'm asking, is there a third party library that actually is meant for those kinds of tasks? Should I use worker threads or simple setTimeouts abstracted by Classes? The response will be sent over SocketIO, that part I already got working as well, it's just the method I'm using im not quite sure how to build.

I'm also open to use another fitting programming language that makes solving this case easier. I'm not in a hurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A polling network request (which it sounds like this is) is non-blocking and asynchronous so it doesn't really take much of your nodejs CPU unless you're doing some heavy-weight computation of the result.

So, a single nodejs thread can make a lot of network requests (for your polling and for sending data over socket.io connection) without adding WorkerThreads or clustering.  This is something that nodejs is very, very good at.

I'm not aware of any third party library specifically for this as you have to custom code looking at the results of the network request anyway and that's most of the coding.  There are a bunch of libraries for making http requests of other servers from nodejs listed [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  My favorite in that list is [got()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got), but you can look at the choices and decide what you like.

As for making the repeated requests, I would probably just use either repeated `setTimeout()` calls or a `setInterval()` call.

You don't say whether you have to make separate requests for every single client that is subscribed to something or whether you can somehow combine all clients watching the same resource so that you use the same polling interval for all of them.  If you can do the latter, that would certainly be more efficient.

If, as you scale, you run into scaling issues, you can then move the polling code to one or more child processes or WorkerThreads and then just communicate back to the main thread via messaging when you have found a new state that needs to be sent to the client.  But, I would not anticipate you would need to code that extra step until you reach larger scale.  As with most scaling things, you would need to code up the more basic option (which should scale well by itself) and then measure and benchmark and see where any bottlenecks are and modify the architecture based on data, not speculation.  Far too often, the architecture is over-designed and over-implemented based on where people think the bottlenecks might be rather than where they actually turn out to be.  Not only does this make the development take longer and end up with more complicated implementation than required, but it can target development at the wrong part of the problem.  Profile, measure, then decide.